# How to display images as cross sections in 3d

Tags: qgis, python, raster, 3d

I want to display a base map and several vertical cross sections in 3D. The base map image is easy to rectify as a geotiff. How can I also display the cross sections?

The cross sections are at present just rectangular images. I can work out the depth/pixel conversion and the surface xy locations for each column of pixles. I have no DTM so the base map is flat and the cross sections simply reside directly underneath.

My preferred options are (1) anything written in Python (2) open source GIS software. eg QGIS, uDig etc. (3) perhaps point cloud software like meshlab?

Regards